# Getting probabilities from odds

Tags: probability, odds-ratio, odds

Simple question here.

Consider an urn with balls of three colors. 50 % of the balls
are red, 30 % black, and the remaining balls green. The experiment is to
draw a ball from the urn.

What is the probability of drawing a black ball? Obviously the answer is .3

I'm trying to use this theorem to arrive at the answer:

Theorem 2.2. Let $A_i, A_2, ... , A_k$ be a partition of S, having odds $q_i$, i.e.
$$\frac{P(A_i)}{P(A_j)} = \frac{q_i}{q_j}$$

Then
$$P(A_i) = \frac{qi}{(qi+··· +qk)}$$

Why is this giving the wrong answer:

P(drawing black ball) = $$\frac{odds \,drawing \,black \,ball}{odds \,drawing \,red + odds \,drawing \,black + \,odds \,drawing \,green}$$

$$=\frac{(.3/.7)}{(.5/.5 + .3/.7 + .2/.8)} = .255 $$

I'm using the defn of odds $= \frac{p}{1-p}$. I think the problem lies with how I'm defining the odds of drawing a red balls; not sure what is should be?

This is an example question from "Probability and Risk Analysis: An Introduction for Engineers" page 23

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\frac{P(A_i)}{P(A_j)} = \frac{q_i}{q_j}$ looks like a probability ratio not an odds ratio. While $\frac{\text{odds drawing black ball}}{\text{odds drawing red } + \text{ odds drawing black } + \text{ odds drawing green}}$ does not look like a probability to me.  I think what the book has done is unconventionally define odds $q_i$ of event $A_i$ as something proportional to probability (but not needing to sum to $1$) so $k \mathbb P(A_i)$ for some $k>0$ while you and I might define it as $\mathbb P(A_i)/\mathbb P(A_i^c)$

Comment: You are applying two different definitions of "odds."  They agree only when $k=2.$  To apply the "theorem" (it's really just basic arithmetic), you should take $q_1:q_2:q_3$ to equal $50:30:20.$